# Zend Application not fully bootstraped when testing with PHPUnit

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, bootstrapping

Zend Framework 1.11.2
PHPUnit 3.5.10
PHP 5.3.1
NetBeans 6.9.1

1. http://pastebin.com/L5bi9AgY
2. I followed [Lebensold's tutorial](http://tinyurl.com/4t6jrbg).

Testing works, even with things like
`$this->dispatch('/');

$this->assertResponseCode(200);`
, but as soon as I require a controller class (pastebin, #33) to instantiate it in the *setUp()* method, I get an error saying that PHPUnit didn't find the parent class (Zend_Controller_Action). So my guess is that I've somehow missed something in bootstrap, because I don't get all the classes loaded (?).

Also, when using the "@covers Class::method" annotation, I get the same type of error.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try requiring the controller class from within your setup, e.g.

```
    class SearchControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

        public function setUp() {

            parent::setUp();

            require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers/SearchController.php');

        }
    }
```

I remember having similar problem and it worked this way.

Comment: Well, now I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object..." in ErrorController.php. Something's still not right.

Comment: @nush. How do you test your controllers? Do you test them by manually instantiating controller classes in your tests? Anyway, if you think this new problem is related to the present (i.e.  required_once problem) consider editing the question to provide more details or creating a new question.

Comment: I have SearchController::_someMethod. I try to instantiate that controller so that I can use the return value of that method. Not sure exactly how to implement this, but I thought this is the way to go. I've got some input regarding this subject on #zftalk and they pointed me to [ZF-8193](http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-8193) and [ZF-10607](http://zendframework.com/issues/browse/ZF-10607). Practically, I'm doing a `$somePrivateProperty = new SearchController()` in the SearchControllerTest.

Comment: @nush. Have a look here: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html . It shows how to test private properties and methods. Maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: @Marcin - I didn't had the "Zend_Loader_Autoloader" in my test bootstrap. Also, I figured out how to call IndexController in my test from [this](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/12/27/testing-zend-framework-controllers/). Thanks for your time.